# Choosing a background image from a pool of images

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and I want to know how may I code/build a starting page of an app that would show a different image each time the app is launched (for the same user)?

I have a set of images available, and I want the starting page to show a different, random, background image each time the user starts the app.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `BackgroundImages` `uri` in an **Array** and use a random generator between `0 to array length` and render it.

```
const Images = ['uri 1', 'uri 2', 'uri 3', 'uri 4']

componentDidMount() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * Images.length);
  this.setState({currentImageIndex: randomNumber})
}

render() {


    return (
        <ImageBackground source={{uri: Images[this.state.currentImageIndex]}}>
            //... Other stuff
        </ImageBackground>
      )
    }
```